# Merge segemented syslog message into a single one

Tags: shell, awk, syslog

I have syslogs which are stored as segments(i.e each syslog message got divided into parts as shown below), i need help with merging those segmented parts as one single message.

below is the sample syslog message:

```
2018-01-06 22:00:00 aaa bbbb xxxxxxxxxx 3 0 text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,...  
2018-01-06 22:00:00 aaa bbbb xxxxxxxxxx 3 1 text,text,text,text,text,...(i.e.continuation of message from part 1)  
2018-01-06 22:00:00 aaa bbbb xxxxxxxxxx 3 2 text,text,text.(i.e.continuation of message from part 2)
```

Here `xxxxxxxxxx` (this field is 10 digit ID) `aaa`,`bbbb` both are headers of syslog message)
Expected Output:

```
2018-01-06 22:00:00 aaa bbbb xxxxxxxxxxx text,text,text...
```

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Edit your Q to show your best attempt at coding a solution to your problem. Sorry, but requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck

Comment: @Cyrus : I agree to what you said, but still this is not an easy task for anyone who is just starting with `awk` . Perhaps he should start with [\[ this \]](https://www.bookdepository.com/Effective-AWK-Programming-4e-Arnold-Robbins/9781491904619?redirected=true&utm_medium=Google&utm_campaign=Base5&utm_source=SG&utm_content=Effective-AWK-Programming-4e&selectCurrency=SGD&w=AF7JAU96Q2ZJK5A80R7SAMJ3&pdg=kwd-104399445939:cmp-711782081:adg-38776039578:crv-164053803561:pid-9781491904619&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIq-7yt7be2AIVD369Ch0o9QvQEAYYASABEgII5vD_BwE) book.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following `awk` command to format your syslog:

**code:**

```
awk '{str=$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5}{for(j=8; j<=NF; j++)a[str]=a[str]" "$j}END{for(i in a)print i""a[i]}' input.log
```

**output for your input:**

```
2018-01-06 22:00:00 aaa bbbb xxxxxxxxxx text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,... text,text,text,text,text,...(i.e.continuation of message from part 1) text,text,text.(i.e.continuation of message from part 2)
```

**explanations:**

- for each line: `for(j=8; j<=NF; j++)a[$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5]=a[$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5]" "$j` will create an array where the index are the concatenation of your first 5 fields this will be reused after for grouping, the value of each cell is populated with the 8th field to the EOL.
- when you read the EOF `END{for(i in a)print i""a[i]}` will be triggered and will display each index/key (i.e. `$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5`) and its content (i.e the grouping of the lines with the same index).

Comment: Brilliant. :-) You made this look so easy with some excellent use of common sense. A small suggestion you could add `{str=$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5}` in the beginning and use `str` elsewhere to make the script even shorter.

Comment: And you do not need the loop too.. In fact  `awk '{str=$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5}{a[str]=a[str]" "$8}END{for(i in a)print i""a[i]}'` will do.

Comment: thanks for the tips! regarding the loop it depends if there are spaces or in the text part